# git - I need to push my latest changes and get error that my branch tip is behind remote counterpart

Tags: git

Usually to resolve this I do git stash. But this time I want to make sure I push my change. Git stash just hides my changes, right? So is there a way to resolve this error message and make sure I push my code?

Comment: git stash doesn't touch your committed changes so it cannot help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch recent changes from the remote server and rebase your current branch against them:

> git pull --rebase

After that (if you are lucky and no one has pushed more changes) you can push again:

> git push

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it and the pull seemed to have worked ok. But the push gave this error: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote

Comment: This means you have more than one branch. Please, post the complete output of ``git push``.

Comment: Actually I did git push origin master. Should I have just done the git push?

Comment: This is the error:  ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://my_url'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and merge the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: It does not matter. Do you see the line like ``master -> origin/master``?

Comment: ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)

Comment: git checkout master
git pull --rebase
git push

Comment: What? What ``git version`` says?

Comment: ``git pull --rebase`` should work just fine... I have 1.8.1 here. That's strange. Try ``git fetch origin`` and then ``git rebase remotes/origin/master``.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26959/discussion-between-genadinik-and-sergey-k)

Comment: I just tried git checkout master and it said my repo is behind by 8 commits. What is the right way to get everything up to the same point?